# dotnet build Error MSB4040: There is no target in the project on jenkins pipeline

Tags: .net, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline>"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" DevopsTest.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.9037.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 2/23/2024 2:55:36 PM.
Project "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest.sln" on node 1 (Build target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest.sln" (1) is building "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest\DevopsTest.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest\DevopsTest.csproj : error MSB4040: There is no target in the project.
Done Building Project "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest\DevopsTest.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest.sln" (Build target(s)).

Build succeeded.

"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest.sln" (Build target) (1) ->
"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest\DevopsTest.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\rpo_pipeline\DevopsTest\DevopsTest.csproj : error MSB4040: There is no target in the project.

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

I have tried add  on .csproj but no luck.

Comment: Restore NuGet Packages didn't worked?